# $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ uniform continuity by definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

$$\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}$$
Hello, I know how to prove without the definition, I tried a lot doing it by the definition of uniform continuity $\left|\frac{\sin \:\left(x\right)}{x}-\frac{\sin \:\left(y\right)}{y}\right|<\xi $ for every $x,y$ close enough.
Thank you very much.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x)=0$ then $f$ is U.C. over $\mathbb{R}$: it is a well-known lemma, a minor variation on "every continuous function over a compact interval is uniformly continuous".

Comment: Thanks that how  i proved it, but im interesting if there is a way doing it directly from definition.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Write $\frac{\sin x}{x} = \int_0^1 \cos (xt)\; dt$ and use a trigonometric identity on $\cos(xt)-\cos(yt)$ (as well as $|\sin(u)|\leq |u|$).

Answer (score 2):

We may prove that $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous. If $\left|x\right|\leq 1$ we have:

$$ \left|\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\leq \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{ |x|^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\cosh(|x|)\leq\cosh 1 $$
and if $|x|>1$ we have
$$ \left|\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}\right|\leq \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2}\leq\sqrt{2}$$
by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.