How to prove that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is uniformly continuous at (0, 1) without using the MVT
How can we prove that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is uniformly continuous at open interval $(0, 1)$ without using the mean value theorem?
I've seen a lot of answers using MVT, but I cannot find how to do it without MVT

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/259767/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2119595/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/436825/42969

I think the question asks for a bare hands proof, not using derivatives or integrals. The second link provided by @Martin R appears (I did not check all the details) to have such a proof.
